# What does java equals() return

Tags: java, equals

I have this code:

```
if(!((s.substring(s.length() - 1)).equals(";"))){
    s = s + ";";
}
```

This code should be checking if the last character of a string is ";" and should add a semicolon to it if it is not the case, only it's doing the exact opposite, it adds a semicolon if the string already ends with one. My code works if I take out the exclamation mark. How is that possible, I read the documentation and .equals() should return true if the two expressions are equal. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: [String.endsWith(String suffix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))

Comment: The code looks ok. Did you try this code in a minimalistic `main` method, just to be sure that _this_ code is really the problem?

Comment: Alternatively have you tried **debugging** the code? I don't think there is an error in the snippet you pasted.

Comment: "How is that possible," It's not possible, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: http://ideone.com/t3QlR8  The code is correct. Please recheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements like this are much easier to debug if you break them down into separate lines. Then you can either use a debugger, as found in Eclipse or other IDE's, or for old school debugging, you can log or print statements each line to show what variables are or aren't

```
int len = s.length();
// Log or print value of `len`
String sub = s.substring(len - 1);
// Log or print value of `sub`
boolean endsSemiColon = sub.equals(";");
// Log or print value of `endsSemiColon`
if(!endsSemiColon) {
    s = s + ";";
}
```

---

PS:

- As tkausl said, this job is done best with `s.endsWith(";")`
- `s = s.concat(";")` is much faster than `s = s + ";"`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!s.endsWith(";")){
    s = s + ";";
}
```

or

```
if(s.charAt(s.length()-1) != ';'){
    s = s + ";";
}
```